# Real distance on image sensor

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, image-processing, camera

I have captured an image using iPhone rear camera. Now I can measure the distance between two points in the image by pixel, and I can easily convert that distance to inch or millimeter using PPI of that iPhone.

```
distance_in_inch = distance_in_pixel / PPI
```

However,  I want to know the distance in inch or millimeter on the image sensor? 
How can I calculate it?

Comment: PPI is typically related to printing the image, it has nothing to do with the sensor. You need to figure out what sensor is in your phone, and find the manufacturer's specs. Those should specify the spacing between pixels on the sensor. But the question is why??? You might be more interested in a distance between the physical points that you photographed?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Because I want to calculate the distance from the phone to real life objects using the triangle rule. Also, for iPhone e.g. iPhone 5, I know the size of a pixel in the sensor size, which is 1.4um. Is it correct to multiply the distance in pixels (measured in captured image) with this value? I doubt about it because the size of the output image from iPhone depends on the parameter `sessionPreset`. When ever I change this parameter, I get a new size e.g. 360x480 or 720 x1280 (In fact, the image is a frame extracted from a `AVCaptureSession`)

Comment: If the image you get is full frame, meaning you get a pixel value from each of the sensor elements, then the physical distance between two neighboring pixels is 1.4um. But if the image you capture is smaller, you need to know if it was subsampled or if a smaller region of the sensor was used. In the latter case nothing changes, you get a smaller field of view. In the former case, the distance between pixels increases by some integer multiple. For example if your sensor is 720x1280, and you get a subsampled 369x480 image, it is likely you pixel size is 2.8um.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you plan to use the triangle rule here. The distance between two points on your sensor, and the distance between those points in real life, are related by the magnification of the lens. Do you know that also?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, I'm aware of the magnification. In fact, the distance can be calculated given the height of the lens with respect to the ground. Regarding the smaller, possibly they have subsampled it. Thanks.